# Navigation Controller not pushing new window

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

i needed to change the tab bar position to the top on my view controller and i found out how to do it. The problem is that now in one of the tabs i need to push a new view controller but when i do , the navigation bar doesn't show up. I tried embedding the new view controller in another navigation controller and it worked (showed the navigation bar) but it didn't showed the back button item. is there a way to do this?

Here some screen shots:

[image: This is the new tabbar controller inside a navigation controller]

this is how i am navigating between tabs

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
switch (item.tag) {
    case 1:
        if (Home == nil) {
            UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                          bundle:nil];
            Home = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Home"];
        }
        [self.view insertSubview:Home.view belowSubview:mainTabBar];
        break;
    case 2:
        if (Activity == nil) {
            UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                          bundle:nil];
            Activity = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Activity"];
        }
        [self.view insertSubview:Activity.view belowSubview:mainTabBar];
        break;

    case 3:
        if (Discover == nil) {
            UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                          bundle:nil];
            Discover = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Discover"];
        }
        [self.view insertSubview:Discover.view belowSubview:mainTabBar];
        break;
    case 4:
        if (Profile == nil) {
            UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                          bundle:nil];
            Profile = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Profile"];

        }
        [self.view insertSubview:Profile.view belowSubview:mainTabBar];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

this is the view controller i need to push.

[image: Profile is one of the tabs and history, following and followers the new view controllers]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone needs this, the way i solved it was making all the tab view controllers childs of the main view controller so it managed the navigation by itself.

```
[self addChildViewController:self.Home];
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather that instantiate your controllers when selecting them, you should instantiate and add them to an array then do this in the AppDelegate when you set up the window:
`self.tabBarController.viewControllers = localViewControllersArray;`